# Azure Data Factory: Data Lake Access Permissions

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-rbac

When I am in the ADF 'author' view and try to create a trigger, after I select the subscription, storage account, it lists the files the trigger can see.

At this point, is it using my credentials/permissions to list those files or ADF's credentials/permissions?

[image]

And in the next tab it shows

[image]

Even though I am asking specifically about a Trigger, I am sure it will be the same with other ADF components like LinkedService, Dataset source/sink etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're totally right. When we create blob evnet trigger,LinkedService,Dataset, Azure Data Factory will do access control and permission checking. It checks the permission for the user. More specifically, it checks whether the Azure account signed in and attempting to create the Event trigger have appropriate access to the relevant Storage account. If the permission check fails, trigger creation also fails.

This [documentation](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory/storage-event-trigger-permission-and-rbac-setting/ba-p/2101782) is useful. Take the creation of a new storage event trigger as an example
[image]

> To successfully create a new or update an existing Storage Event Trigger, the Azure account signed into the Data Factory and publish the event trigger needs to have appropriate access to the relevant storage account. Otherwise, the operation with fail with **Access Denied**.